# What's the difference?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String vs string in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c)

What's the difference between string and String, if any?

They both seem to perform the same function, but the casing is different. So, there are only TWO things that are different (that I know of) and they are:

When spelled with a capital letter, the color of its text is Blue in VStudio.
Casing.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116523/string-vs-string. Please do some searching before asking a question.

Answer (score 4):

`string` is a keyword which aliases type `System.String`. `String` is just a short name for type `System.String`, which is brought into your scope when you write `using System;`. Similarly, `object` is a keyword alias for `System.Object`, `int` is a keyword alias for `System.Int32`, [and so on](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx).

VS highlights keywords with blue, which is why `string` is blue, while `String` is not.

Answer (score 2):

they are the same. string is an alias for String.

Answer (score 0):

"string" is simply an alias for "System.String"