# String vs string

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C# what is the difference between String and string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-what-is-the-difference-between-string-and-string)

Should I use `string` or `String` when declaring a basic string variable in **c#** and does it matter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/215255/string-vs-string-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/116523/string-vs-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/in-c-sharp-whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It doesn't matter, though it's best to be consistent: lower-case `string` [is an alias for `String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

Comment: To expand, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88418.aspx

Comment: I find it weird to start a class name with lowercase character since it breaks every other platform convention..

Answer (score 32):

I like `string` because VS highlights it in dark blue (which makes it awesomer).

Comment: Besides being funny, he is also 100% correct.

Comment: Which part is correct? Mine doesn't highlight in dark blue: http://studiostyl.es/schemes/wekeroad-ink

Comment: And awesomer is better...

Answer (score 7):

The `string` keyword is an alias for `System.String`.

(The same goes for `int - System.Int32` `long - System.Int64` and so on)

C# doesn't have two different representations for primitives the same way that Java does. (Where an `int` is far different from an `Integer`)

In most cases it is best to use lowercase `string` because it is an alias to the fully qualified `System.String`.  This way you can avoid type conflicts if there is another `String` type somewhere in your code.

Comment: You'd have to be nuts to name a custom class String. Though I guess you might just be using a library built by someone else who is nuts...

Answer (score 1):

They both point to the same class. It doesn't matter which one you use.